# Python download a file

Tags: python, linux, urllib2

I'm unsure how to do this. One way is:

```
import urllib.request;
urllib.request.urlretrieve('www.example.com/file.tar', 'file.tar')
```

Another way would be:

```
import urllib.request;

#Set as appropriate
userAgent = ....;

req = urllib.request.Request('www.example.com/file.tar', headers={'User-Agent' : userAgent});
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req);

#Save the file
f = open('file.tar', 'wb');
f.write(response.read());
f.close()
```

I'm not sure which method to use. I'll be downloading many files (with a pattern filename) in a loop. However, I would like to be able to set up a user-agent header. It's not critical but I'd like to.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I prefer the first method but I don't know how to set the user-agent header with urlretrieve.

Comment: I dont understand. What is wrong with your second approach if you want to customize the headers? Does it not work?

Comment: It works but I am unsure what the urllib.request.urlretrieve is used for then? Also I need to create a response object on each iteration (in case I put it in a loop). The code is also a lot longer so I thought there must be a way to use urlretrieve and set the headers. After all urlretrieve saves many lines.

Comment: `urlretrieve` is exactly what the docs say: A higher-level function, to be used simply to copy a network resource to a local file. You don't get much control, like headers, which is why you have to drop down to a request object. You are doing the manual process of `urlretrieve` so it does require a few more lines.

Comment: I understand. That's what I was unsure about.

Comment: I would strongly suggest using http://python-requests.org/ (a higher-level wrapper around urllib3) -- it not only provides a simpler API, but also does things like keepalive and session management for you, without any extra work. If you're retrieving lots of files from the same server, keepalive might be a substantial performance benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am moving what started as comments, to an answer...

Your second example is pretty much doing what it needs to, in making a request object with a custom header and then reading the results into a local file.

`urlretrieve` is a higher level function so it only does exactly what the docs say: Downloads a network resource to a local file and tells you where the file is. If you don't like the slightly lower level approach of your second example and you want more higher-level functionality, you can look into using the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.7/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) library

Answer (score 0):

As @jdi said, you may use the [requests](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) library. This is also mentioned on https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html. You will need to pip the library, e.g.

```
pip install requests
```

My code looks like this:

```
import requests

def download_file(url):
    file = requests.get(url)
    return file.text
```

It can't be easier.