# Need to download a file from a web browser using python

Tags: python

I am trying to use Python 2.7 to open a web browser and download and save a linked kml file.

The website is:
rmgsc.cr.usgs.gov/outgoing/GeoMAC/ActiveFirePerimeters.kml

When I run the code below, a new kml file appears to be saved on my drive, however it does not bring over the entire file.  Instead of 154MB, it brings over a file that is only 17 bytes.

I can either go to the website (rmgsc.cr.usgs.gov/outgoing/GeoMAC/) and then click on a link named "ActiveFirePerimeters.kml", or go to the website with the kml file name included which automatically initiates a download.  In IE9 I would then need to click a "Save" button, however in Chrome it appears to automatically download.  However in both only 17bytes come across....

Here is my code for Internet Explorer:

```
import os, webbrowser
target_dir = r"C:\DataTest"
filename = "ActiveFirePerimeters.kml"

fullname = os.path.join(target_dir,filename)
with open(fullname,"w") as f:
   f.write("<html>....</html>")

url = "rmgsc.cr.usgs.gov/outgoing/GeoMAC/ActiveFirePerimeters.kml"
webbrowser.open(url,True,True)

os.system("taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe")
```

Comment: Why are you opening the file in a web browser? Can you not directly download the file?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899031/python-download-a-file?rq=1

Comment: If I hit this URL FF reports file size 1,7Mb. Maybe a server fault ...

Comment: @Nadh - I only need to download the latest version of the file.  The file is updated on a regular basis.  I want to grab the file and download it to my computer then run a python script on it, etc.  If I don't have to open a browser, then that would be better.

Comment: @PeterMmm - The file is updated regularly so the size will change throughout the day.  How can I download it to a specific file on my computer via Python 2.7?  I'm not a programmer so I need an example of a working code instead of a generic piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

Are you required to use Internet Explorer for some reason to accomplish this task ? I would suggest taking a look at the `urllib` module : http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html. In particular, you can download a resource easily using :

```
import urllib

urllib.urlretrieve(source_url, local_file_path)
```

Comment: @Imjohns3 - No, I don't have a specific browser.  I was experiment with both to see which would work easier.  Than for the code.  I'll give it a try.  So for clarification, how does this work?  I just tried to replace the source_url with "http://rmgsc.cr.usgs.gov/outgoing/GeoMAC/ActiveFirePerimeters.kml" and the local_file_path with "C:\DataTest\ActiveFiresPerimeters.kml" and it did not work.  Any clues?

Comment: You probably need to include the protocol in your URL (e.g., `'http://'`)

Comment: Did the above solution work? I’m trying to do the exact same thing.